# Flex resize image inside updateDisplayList

Tags: apache-flex, image, resize

I have a custom component which is an HBox & I'm trying to resize a child which happens to be an image. This is image is inside a VBox which is also a child of the HBox. I have a number of these images so In UpdateDisplayList I call:

```
myimageArray[0-5].setActualSize(50,50);
```

but the image is never resized it just stays a large default size. The images source is a url path and I'm wondering if that is what is causing the problem?

Comment: What you're claiming is happening doesn't make sense.  Please provide more code, possibly even a running sample.  I also wonder if you're overusing containers.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `setActualSize()` for each array item manually:

```
for each (var uiComponent:UIComponent in myimageArray)
{
    uiComponent.setActualSize(50,50);
}
```

Or, if you need to resize only first 6 elements:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < Math.min(6, myimageArray.length); i++)
{
    myimageArray[i].setActualSize(50,50);
}
```